# modify the post data of a request in firefox extension

Tags: http, firefox, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to trap an http request, change some of its post parameters and send the modified request.
I tried using the setData method of upload stream to modify the request, but the same original request is sent.

I have the following code execute on the "http-on-modify-request" :

```
//rewind the request to read post body  
channel= subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
channel=channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);  
channel = channel.uploadStream;  
channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream)
                .seek(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);  
var stream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"]
                .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIBinaryInputStream);  
stream.setInputStream(channel);  
var postBytes = stream.readByteArray(stream.available());  
poststr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);  

//change the poststr

poststr=poststr.replace(....);  
stringStream.setData(poststr, poststr.length);  
//changing the postdata  
channel = channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);  
channel = channel.uploadStream;  
channel = channel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream)
          .seek(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);  
channel.uploadStream.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIMIMEInputStream);  
channel.uploadStream.setData(stringStream);  
channel.send();
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I tried aborting the initial request and starting with a fresh request, but then the page doesn't load at all.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can use the `{}` button to make your code look like code when asking a question.

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly call `channel.send` from http-on-modify-request -- Firefox will do that for you after it calls your code. You could try taking that out and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey I figured out what was wrong!! :)

The uploadstream.setData has a bug.
It sets the request method of the channel to PUT as opposed to POST
So we need to change that after the setData call.
The following seems to solve the problem :)

```
channel.uploadStream.setData(stringStream);   
channel.requestMethod = "POST";
```

@ MatrixFrog :  You are right. I don't need to call `channel.send`. That part is taken care of :)